# Algorithm to divide a given number in two proportions by one of the component of that number

Tags: java, algorithm, linear-programming

Please help me understand the JAVA algorithm or technique to be used for below problem.

There are three components 

a = n * r / 100 

r = (a*100) / n 

n = (a/r) * 100

It is required to divide a & n into two parts in such a ratio that r should be between 0.012 and 2.000.

Example:

Given details 

 n=10 ,r=0.8  ,a=10 * 0.8 / 100 = 0.08

Below should be the values for n,r and a
r should be between 0.012 and 2.000 
n and r  can be negative as well.

1)n=6 ,r=0.2 , a= n * r / 100 = 10 * 0.2 / 100 = 0.012

2)n=4 ,r=(a*100) / n = 0.068 * 100 / 4 = 1.7 ,a= 0.068

Comment: And your question is... What do you want to do? What I can see in this question is that you are crazily twisting the equation `rn=100a`.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't tell us what it is that you don't understand.

Comment: Hi PEMapModder, yes rn=100a is the equation.

Comment: Hey azurefrog - What I don't understand is that how will I divide a & n in two components (as given in the example in my first post) such that r is in the given range using java program. The example I gave is just for one input, there are be many different values of n and a with different range of r. Sorry if I am confusing you.

Comment: What does "divide in two components" even mean? For any value of `n` you can randomly choose any arbitrary value of `r` between 0.012 and 2.000, and simply calculate `a` from that. --- I'm afraid I don't understand what "components", "parts", and "ratio" has to do with anything. Please clarify question.

Comment: I don’t understand either what are the givens and what is the expected output. I don’t understand either which part/s of the task you are having problems with.

Comment: input ==> n = 10 , a = 0.08 , r = 0.8 , r min = 0.012 , r max = 2.00 
output ==> [1] n = 6 , a = 0.012 , r = 0.2  [2] n = 4 , a = 0.068 , r = 1.7
 ==> adding output line [1] & [2] should total to the input value of "n" and "a" 
input "n" = 10 and "a" = 0.8, adding outputs of "n" which is 6 +4 = 10 and "a" which is 0.012 + 0.068 = 0.8 respectively.
to achieve this we need to choose correct value of "r" which should be between the given range.
My question is what should be the java algorithm to choose the value of "r", I believe it will be an iterative process to choose the value of "r" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was solved using triangulation. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I’ve got it now: Given n, a and r you want to find n1, a1, r1, n2, a2 and r2 so that n1 + n2 = n, a1 + a2 = a, r1 * n1 = 100 * a1, r2 * n2 = 100 * a2, 0.012 <= r1 <= 2.0 and the same for r2. Is this correct? 6 unknowns, 4 equations and 4 inequalities, that may easily give infinitely many solutions.

If the input fulfils r * n = 100 * a and n is at least 2, you can find a number of the solutions with:

```
    r = a * 100 / n;
    for (int n1 = 1; n1 < n; n1++) {
        double proportion = (double) n1 / (double) n;
        System.out.println("[1] n = " + n1 + " a = " + a * proportion + " r = " + r);
        proportion = 1 - proportion;
        System.out.println("[2] n = " + (n - n1) + " a = " + a * proportion + " r = " + r);
    }
```

If the input doesn’t fulfil the equation, it’s getting trickier, and as far as I can tell there may be 0 or infinitely many solutions.

Disclaimer: I can’t remember much of the linear programming I learned in my youth, so I’m not trying to apply any of it.

Edit: refined version, ignores `r` from input, only prints solutions with r in the specified range, but may print twice as many solutions as before, which were already way too many.

```
    // without loss of generality assume n1 <= n2
    for (int n1 = 1; n1 <= n / 2; n1++) {
        int n2 = n - n1;
        // a1 should be >= rMin * n1 / 100 and also = a - a2, that is >= a - rMax * n2 / 100
        double a1Min = Math.max(rMin * n1 / 100, a - (rMax * n2 / 100));
        double a1Max = Math.min(rMax * n1 / 100, a - rMin * n2 / 100);
        if (a1Min <= a1Max) {
            // print solution with a1 = a1Min
            System.out.println("[1] n = " + n1 + " a = " + a1Min + " r = " + 100 * a1Min / n1);
            double a2 = a - a1Min;
            System.out.println("[2] n = " + n2 + " a = " + a2 + " r = " + 100 * a2 / n2);
            // print solution with a1 = a1Max
            System.out.println("[1] n = " + n1 + " a = " + a1Max + " r = " + 100 * a1Max / n1);
            a2 = a - a1Max;
            System.out.println("[2] n = " + n2 + " a = " + a2 + " r = " + 100 * a2 / n2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: but the "r" doesn't seems to be in the range anytime.

Comment: The first version calculates r from the input and does not check it against the range (but if it’s outside, I don’t think it could be inside in any solution). The refined version was made to calculate r1 and r2 both within the range, and print no solution if it cannot. If it behaves differently, it’s an error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ole V.V for the solution.I ran your code against below

```
double a = 10000;//can be 40,000,000
double n = 50000;//can b 5,000,000,000
double r = a * 100 / n;//should be between a given range
```

However ,in the output "r" is always constant(20.0)for each and every iteration
We actually need r between an given range and it should be different for [1] and [2].
Code should actually ONLY print n1,a1,r1 and n2,a2,r2 ,where "r" falls between the given range of "r" 
For a bigger number of "a" and "r" , your code will throw out of memory.

Comment: The result you got is as I had expected. When I said “If the input fulfils r * n = 100 * a”, I was also assuming 0.012 <= r <= 2.0. Your r is not in that range. Furthermore, there is no solution for this input. For very big n my code will certainly print many more solutions than you would want to have, but I doubt it would run into an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: I forgot to say, I was also assuming that n is an `int` greater than 0. If n is a long or other data type and greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, my code probably runs forever.

Comment: I don’t think you should use the answer field for comments. This is not an answer to the question after all. :-) For new information about the question, such as possible values of a and n, edit your question. For other comments, use the “add a comment” link under the answer.